# Checking permissions of FTP (on server that possibly does not allow directory listing)

Tags: ftp

It is possible to check read/write permissions for given directory on FTP server by using command line?

I know there is a following way:

- Enter to the parent directory
- use `ls` command

But I cannot go this way due to fact the `ls` command can be unavailable for security reasons in some servers. Uploading a file for test purpose is not an option for me as well.

It seems the best way will be to check permissions in working directory only. How to do that?

Comment: `ls .` should do the job. Without `ls` you are probably screwed.

Comment: So it is FTP or SFTP? Use the correct tag only! What FTP command-line client is that? What platform? Are you restricted to a certain client at all? Do you really need a generic solution that works on both servers that do and do to support `ls`?

Comment: @Martin At this moment i checking the posibility of do in command-line client which is built-in Windows 7. In final solution i will use my java implementation to make a check of it. So i suppose if it is possible in windows ftp client then it will be possible in java implemntation as well. Im not limited by client or library, generally my case is that i cant rely on server configuration or server software, so in one of then i can use 'ls' command in other i can use someting else if there are other option.

Comment: Note that the server can disable "for security reasons" any command, so with this attitude you cannot do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have:

- obsolete `LIST` command (`ls` in Widows `ftp.exe`) - parse the response with format, that is undefined, but commonly like:

  ```
  > LIST
  < 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
  < drwxr-xr-x   3 user group       4096 Aug  6 08:37 name
  ```
- modern `MLSD` command (not supported by `ftp.exe`) - parse the common (though not really standard) `UNIX.mode` "fact"

  ```
  > MLSD
  < 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD
  < modify=20150806063726;perm=flcdmpe;type=dir;unique=FD01U404A6;UNIX.group=505;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.owner=10005; name
  ```
- obsolete `STAT` command (not supported by `ftp.exe` explicitly, but invokable using `quote STAT path`) - parse the response with format, that is undefined, but commonly like:

  ```
  > quote STAT name
  < drwxr-xr-x   3 user group       4096 Aug  6 08:37 name
  ```
- modern `MLST` command (not supported by `ftp.exe` explicitly, but invokable using `quote MLST path`) - parse the common (though not really standard) `UNIX.mode` "fact"

  ```
  > MLST name
  < 250-Start of list for name
  <  modify=20150806063729;perm=flcdmpe;type=dir;unique=FD01U4104C;UNIX.group=505;UNIX.mode=0755;UNIX.owner=10005; name
  < 250 End of list
  ```

I all cases, the server must support the command in the first place. All servers do support the `LIST`. Support for the other commands (`STAT`, `MLSD` and `MLST`) is not universal.

Comment: Some FTP clients also support the `STAT` FTP command, _e.g._ `ftp> rstatus file`, and _some_ FTP servers return the same file information in a `STAT` response as they would for _e.g._ `LIST`.

Comment: @Castaglia True, I've added that to my answer.